# Python plotly express line chart with cumulative sum

Tags: python, plotly

In essence, I would like to plot a line chart of my data `y ~ x | g`, that is I would like to plot the cumulative sums of y separately and colored by groups, without having to add these to the data. Why? Because there are many such columns which I would like to plot and I do not want to add a cumulative column for each one. Consider the following example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "y" : [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "x" : [1,2,3,1,2,3],
    "g" : ["a","a","a","b","b","b"]
})

import plotly.express as px
px.line(df, y="y", x="x", color="g")
```

I am looking for a way to add an argument of sorts to tell plotly to plot the cumulative sum by groups. Is there such a feature or workaround?

Comment: You might just use `y=df['y'].cumsum()`. You don't need to add new columns

Comment: @ALai That won't work because the cumulative sum has to be by groups.

Comment: Then I think you should update your sample code to better reflect your use case

Comment: the px.ecdf() function might also be very interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- simple **pandas** `join()` to `cumsum()` with required `groupby()`
- dataframe for **plotly express** can now access any **cumsum** column or column that has not been summed

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "y" : [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "x" : [1,2,3,1,2,3],
    "g" : ["a","a","a","b","b","b"]
})

import plotly.express as px
px.line(df.join(df.groupby("g", as_index=False).cumsum(), rsuffix="_cumsum"), y="y_cumsum", x="x", color="g")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought @rob-raymond 's answer would be able to save me ...
but it took me another days to crack that up.

Best cases: all "categories" have the same 'x' values
... then the proposed solution works. Problem solved

However, in real life, we often have different x values for the different categories... and the generated cumulative area charts quickly turn super odd

Each time a category is missing an 'x' value, the category shows a cumulative value of zero for those 'x', while the points before and after are themself well cumulating.

The heck of an headache to figure out ... and then some more intensive try & error to fix.

Here is the complete solution that handles both data with and without gaps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
# my 3 columns: ('type', 'nb_objects', 'dt')

# Create cumulative sum:
df.set_index('type', inplace = True) 
cumsum = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['nb_objects'].cumsum().values, index=x['dt'])) 

# filling in gaps to enable plotly to add data for same x :
try:
   no_gap_df_wide_format = cumsum.unstack(level=1).fillna(method='ffill', axis=1) 

   # getting back to column format:
   no_gap_df = no_gap_df_wide_format.stack().rename_axis(index={None: 'type', 'dt':'dt'}).rename('nb_objects_cumsum').reset_index()

except ValueError:
   # there is no gap to fill
   no_gap_df = pd.DataFrame(df_data).join(pd.DataFrame(df_data).groupby("type", as_index=False).cumsum(), rsuffix="_cumsum")

fig = px.area(no_gap_df,x='dt',
              y='nb_objects_cumsum',            
              color="type", 
)
```